# Run a C++ Project main() multiple times in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++

I have a Visual Studio C++ project. If I want to only run it once, I can simply manually input the arguments of

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

into `debugging options` and then click <kbd>Debug</kbd>.

However now, I wish to **run multiple times with different parameters in one go**. e.g. I wish to run it like this:

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    main(i);
}
```

How may I do this with Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe it's technically legal (per the standard) to call `main`. Even if it were, you'd be passing the wrong parameters (`argc == 1` and `argv == ${DEITY}_ONLY_KNOWS`).

This is a problem I would perhaps solve with a cmd script. Just make sure that your program is compiled, then run something like:

```
@echo off
cd \path\to\debug\dir
rem this bit can be as complex as cmd.exe allows:
for /l %%a in (0,1,50) do (
    for /l %%b in (0,1,10) do (
        echo data.txt result.txt %%a %%b
    )
)
```

This will run a command (`echo` in my case so you can see it working but you should replace that with your actual executable name, and modify the cd command to select the proper directory) 561 times (51 x 11) with the first two arguments fixed and the last two running 0-50 and 0-10, the output of which finishes:

```
: : : : : : : : : :
data.txt result.txt 49 7
data.txt result.txt 49 8
data.txt result.txt 49 9
data.txt result.txt 49 10
data.txt result.txt 50 0
data.txt result.txt 50 1
data.txt result.txt 50 2
data.txt result.txt 50 3
data.txt result.txt 50 4
data.txt result.txt 50 5
data.txt result.txt 50 6
data.txt result.txt 50 7
data.txt result.txt 50 8
data.txt result.txt 50 9
data.txt result.txt 50 10
```

There *may* be a way to get VS to do this automatically as part of a build/run sequence but I'm not aware of any (and I tend to opt for the simplest solutions most of the time).

---

You could, of course, refactor your code so that you rename `main` to something else then have a filter `main` as follows:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Do this normally:
    return worker (argc, argv);

    // Or do this for debugging:
    // int stat = 0;
    // for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    //     // construct argv-lookalike based on i.
    //     stat = worker (myargc, myargv);
    //     if (stat != 0) break;
    // }
    // return stat;
```

However, the construction of an argv-array is not trivial since you have to follow the same rules as laid out in the standard, specifically that `argc` and `argv` must agree, `argv` must an array of character pointers (one more than is indicated by `argc`) so that each argument is a C-style string, `argv[0]` must represent the program name, `argv[argc]` must be NULL, and so on.

It's probably easiest to use the `cmd` script solution and let the startup code take care of all that argument preparation for you.

Comment: you could probably open multiple instances of VS and run the code in each instance, a bit messy though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How may I write the cmd script for this particular main()?  pastie.org/8382923 say my arg0, arg1 are always data.txt and result.txt. My arg2 loops from 0-50 and my arg3 loops from 0-10? Really a newbie to C++ and never heard of cmd script. Thanks

Comment: @perfectionm1ng, have updated the sample `cmd` file to show one way of doing that.

Comment: Thank you so much! One last question, since I don't want the new result to overwrite the previous result, I may need to have different outputfile name as well. I modify result.txt to result%%a.txt like this http://pastie.org/8382994 . I did not see any txt file generated. Where went wrong?

Comment: @perfectionm1ng, not sure why but since the output is within your program rather than the script, it's almost certainly an issue with the program. The output of your echo at the pastie works fine though it uses `a` only - you'll probably want to use both `a` and `b`.

Comment: When I manually run the project, a result file will be created. I am wondering is it because of this line here http://pastie.org/8382994#3 it does not seem like machine language. Also, I wonder why no .exe is specified in the cmd file?

Comment: @perfection, my cmd file uses echo to show you the parameters. I may not have made it clear enough but you should use your actual executable rather than echo. I'll clarify.

Comment: Visual Studio can run such a CMD script, if you specify `CMD.EXE` as the executable to start for debugging, and `-C <script.name>` as the arguments.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ it is illegal to call `main` within a program (C++11 §3.6.1/3). However, *any* work that is done inside `main` can easily be done in another function.

```
int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    foo( argc, argv );
}

int foo( int argc, char** argv ) {
    // do something
}
```

At this point, feel free to call `foo(...)` as many times from within your program (or Visual Studio debugger) as you want.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have this hypothetical program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        cerr << "bad input" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    auto arg = atoi(argv[1]);
    cout << (2*arg) << endl;
}
```

You could use a batch script.  Save the following as `test.bat` in the same directory as your program executable. Type `help` or specifically `help for` in a command prompt for more information about batch file commands:

```
@echo off
for /L %%i in (0,1,9) do prog.exe %%i
```

Output:

```
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
```

Or you could refactor main to loop and call a function:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func(int arg)
{
    cout << (2*arg) << endl;
}

int main()
{
    for(auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        func(i);
}
```

Output:

```
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
```

Comment: Thanks for the step-by-step solution. 1. Inside the project folder I don't have anything.exe. What I have are Microsoft Visual Studio Solution and VC++ Project. What may I do? 2. The parameter inputs of main() is like this: http://pastie.org/8382923 How may I write my batch file? Thanks! Really a newbie to C++. :)

Comment: After you build the project, the `.exe` will normally be in a `Debug` or `Release` directory beside the solution.